# EJS - write js variable in style tag property

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have this code:

```
<%
let obj = anExternObject;
for(int i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
    let background = `url('${obj[i].url}') -${obj[i].left}px -${obj[i].top}px no-repeat`;
    let item = obj[i].name;
%>

<div style="background: <%=background%>;" data-item="<%=item%>"></div>

<% } %>
```

The `<%=variable%>` works for all attributes, but not for `style` one.
I get an error on ejs tag `<%`, so I must surround it by single quotes (so convert it to string) like this:

```html
<div style="background: '<%=background%>';" data-item="<%=item%>"></div>
```

but in this case it's doesn't working, because I must have integer values for the `-${obj[i].left}px -${obj[i].top}px`, while I'm getting this:

```html
<div style="background: 'url(my/url.ong) -100px -50px not-repeat';"></div>
```

How could I do to put `obj[i].left` and `obj[i].top` integers in `style` property ?